# Trouble mounting a Windows 2008R2 share on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, mount, permissions, windows, samba

I am attempting to mount files on my 2008R2 server from my Ubuntu 16.04 server using this command in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
//serverip/sharename  /shares/windowsshare  cifs  username=msusername,password=mspassword,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

I setup an account on the win server for the Ubuntu server to use, when i use these credentials, it gives me:

```
mount error(13) : Permission denied
```

but when I use the credentials of the administrator account on my win server it mounts with no problem.  I have changed all the credentials of the Ubuntu account (on the windows server) to match the "ms" administrator, and yet it still does not work.

Please can I get some advice as I have tried searching and can’t find a solution. I do not want to continue using the admin account to access my shares.

Comment: You should edit your question and include the command you're trying to use when you get the `mount` error.

Comment: @Melebius i tried all the accounts setup on the windows machine, none worked via ubuntu except the msAdmin account. they all worked fine for windows to windows communication

Comment: @Diabsiniman OK, another guess: Have you tried to include domain/workgroup of the user in the `mount` options? One more tip: Use `mount` command for debugging, don’t move to `/etc/fstab` until it’s working.

Comment: @Melebius i have already tried that (the domain/workgroup) i used it thusly "username=winserver/winuser" like i said, it mounts on the winadmin account an none other.